# C# 6 Использование многопоточных коллекций вместо массивов

Tags: c#, .net

Есть массив int[][] a, к которому необходимо обеспечить многопоточный доступ на все операции с данными. Для этого нужно использовать многопоточные коллекции ConcurrentDictionary. Затрудняюсь выбрать между `ConcurrentDictionary<int,int[]>` и `ConcurrentDictionary<int,ConcurrentDictionary<int,int[]>>`(ключ обозначает номер элемента массива). В чем будет разница? Имеет ли смысл записывать в Cuncurrent-коллекцию другую Concurrent-коллекцию, как показано во втором случае, и почему? Будут ли случаться коллизии в каком-либо из этих вариантов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, следите что именно вы пишите. Без разметки у вас все что было в угловых скобках съел парсер и вопрос звучал очень странно.

Comment: лучше `ConcurrentDictionary<int,ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>>` здесь же всего двумерный массив

Comment: Да, второй вариант выглядит как ConcurrentDictionary<int,ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>> - без [].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать Concurrent-контейнеры только в том случае, когда семантика вашего контейнера — простое хранилище несвязанных данных. И то проще, разумеется, использовать volatile-доступ (без него ваше записанное значение может не записаться, а прочитанное не обновиться).

В остальных случаях стоит завести `lock` и блокировать нужные операции.

Почему Concurrent-контейнер — не лучшая идея? Обычно у вас структура данных обладает внутренней нетривиальной семантикой и собственными инвариантами. Потокобезопасность и есть на самом деле гарантия сохранения внутренних инвариантов при многопоточном доступе.

Например, если ваша структура данных — квадратная матрица, и у вас есть операция вычисления детерминанта, никакой Concurrent-контейнер не будет блокировать всю матрицу на время вычислений, а значит, результат при многопоточном доступе непредсказуем и скорее всего неверен. Если ваша структура данных допускает матричное сложение, то снова-таки Concurrent-контейнер не будет блокировать всю матрицу на время вычислений, и результат будет неверен.

Итак, вы должны:

1. Жёстко определить ваши операции.
2. Создать приватный блокировочный объект (`private object mutex = new object()`).
3. Выразить операции в виде методов, и оборачивать доступ к данным конструкцией `lock (mutex) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

Заменять массив на `ConcurrentDictionary` из соображений потокобезопасности - довольно странная идея, ведь большинство операций `ConcurrentDictionary` для массива не имеют смысла.

Фактически, единственными операциями над массивом являются получение элемента и обновление. Но для потокобезопасного получения элемента массива не надо напрягаться - ведь чтение `int` всегда атомарно. Для обновления же элемента массива можно использовать любую `Interlocked`-операцию. Так, методу `TryUpdate` из `ConcurrentDictionary` напрямую соответствует так называемая операция [`CAS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref a[5], 10, 20);
```

Но, возможно, вам и не нужен был массив исходно: вам понадобилось добавлять в массив элементы или удалять их. В таком случае вы правильно сделали что решили заменить массив на что-то еще - ведь пересоздание массива атомарной операцией не является. Какую коллекцию вам при этом лучше использовать - зависит исключительно от того, что вам с ней надо будет делать.

Могу посоветовать только попробовать использовать разные варианты и посмотреть, получается ли в каждом из них использовать только потокобезопасные операции.

Также предложу еще один возможный заменитель для такого массива:

- `ConcurrentDictionary<int,int[]>`
- `ConcurrentDictionary<int,ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>>`
- `ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>`

---

Но должен вас предупредить: комбинация нескольких потокобезопасных операций далеко не всегда потокобезопасна в целом. Если вы чувствуете, что путаетесь в этом всем - возможно, вам не следует пытаться использовать lock-free алгоритмы, а достаточно "традиционного" подхода с блокировками.

Простое использование конструкции `lock` сделает любую операцию потокобезопасной (если, конечно же, вы будете использовать вызов `lock` с одним и тем же объектом для любых обращений к массиву).

Comment: А что и где можно почитать, чтобы разобраться с небезопасностью комбинаций потокобезопасных коллекций? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если значения вложенной коллекции меняются то лучше:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int,ConcurrentDictionary<int,int>>
```

так как массив это ссылочный тип и фактически в ConcurrentDictionary запишится только ссылка на него, а доступ к элементам вложенного массива так и останется небезопасным.

А если не меняются и вы манипулируете вложенными массивами как объектами значениями то:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int,int[]>
```

Конфликты могут возникнуть в любом из этих вариантов, для их разрешения есть метод AddOrUpdate и его перегрузки.